# android ripple effect on tapping the screen

Tags: android, animation, android-4.2-jelly-bean

How can I get a ripple kind effect whenever a user taps on the screen of my app.
The effect should be same like below image link:-
[click here](http://skp.samsungcsportal.com/upload/namo/FAQ/ca/img12%5B9%5D.gif)

So does android has any apis for it..or I have to just make one from 2d graphics or something?

Answer (score 1):

There is a guy named [nikwen](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=5101348) in xda-developers who made(found) this, available to developers(not Samsung, Nokia and etc.)

Here link to this "Ripple effect"
([Holo-themed transparent demo overlays](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2419939))